# Output voltage halved in 3-phase SPWM inverter simulation

Tags: pwm, inverter, switching, three-phase, sine

I am just trying to simulate a 3-phase inverter connected to a star-connected load controlled through sine PWM modulation.

In real life, I would expect a carrier that would go from zero to one. As such, I've scaled my per-unit modulation index to half and shifted it upwards by 0.5. Below is how I am generating my gating signals:

[image]

For some reason, however, my output is always half of my demanded input. My goal is to get an SPWM + inverter block that takes in a voltage demand input and produces it at the output.

Any ideas to why am I getting half of my demanded sinewave? Is my strategy for getting the switching signals (above) correct?

(I only put a screenshot of the PWM generation blocks because this is where I believe the error might be. Otherwise, my simulation is quite simple and only includes a 3-phase inverter switched in a unipolar scheme, with a single dc link.)

For reference: this is my demand phase voltage (blue) vs averaged output phase voltage (orange):

[image]

Full circuit for reference:

[image]

Comment: Is this the phase-to-phase voltage? One leg should have top side modulation from 0 to 100% while the bottom side is the inverse (complement). Then the adjacent legs will be phase shifted by 120 and 240 degrees.

Comment: Hi there,
Yes they are the phase to neutral voltages: I've connected my load in star

Comment: Can you show the actual H-bridge? Usually the outputs are phase-to-phase. so phase-to-neutral would be divided by sqrt(3). To get the waveform you show, you would need a positive and negative DC bus link.

Comment: Hi there Paul, 
Just put my circuit diagram in my edit

Comment: @your_best_friend It looks like your gain block has the *name* `1/V_dc2` (suggesting the possibility of another gain block) but, the gain is `1/(2*V_dc)`. Are you simply renaming it, thinking you're modifying the gain?

Comment: Ah, I just copied a block that I used earlier and forgot to change the name, the gain I intend is 1/(2*V_dc), which is the value in the gain block

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are generating a PWM sine wave on each phase which has a zero reference at 1/2 V_dc. You are using the common connection at the middle of the star motor connection as a neutral reference, which will be the average of all three phase signals. This voltage will vary around the half voltage point of the DC link, and should result in phase-neutral peak voltage of Vdc/sqrt(3). But I think you are assuming neutral of Vdc/2.